# Persistence sleepiness

Tags: health, sleep

I kept on observing it. If I sleep for 6-7 hours, I will feel sleepy all throughout the day. I tried sleeping 11pm for a change, then I woke up 9am. I still feel sleepy. I can't work on my homeworks and thesis because of this persistence sleepiness.. Maybe there is something wrong with my health. What might that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you have concerns about your health, you need to go to your doctor. Assuming that your doctor says that this isn't due to some disease, then it's reasonable to assume that you need more sleep; 6 to 7 hours isn't all that much. If you don't want to feel sleepy, you'll need about 8 hours of sleep and a bit more if you are below the age of 25. Most people who say that they need only 6 hours of sleep actually need more sleep, but they are better than average at tolerating the effects of sleep deprivation. Recent research showed that [The activity of hundreds of genes was altered when people's sleep was cut to less than six hours a day for a week](http://www.bbc.com/news/health-21572686) . So, you're better of feeling sleepy if you sleep less than 8 hours so that you are forced to sleep more.

Comment: Usually if I sleep at least 10 hours, I would have my optimum energy but once evening comes, say 8pm, I really begin to feel sleepy; I usually sleep for 7-8 hours during school days from 12am to 7am. Once school ends, I would need to do my homework during evenings but I cant because of my sleepiness. The reason why I think there is something wrong with me is other students can sleep 7-8 hours a day without feeling sleepy the whole evening. Some more information... I don't eat breakfast before going to school. I only eat lunch and dinner. Maybe these have effects on my sleepiness?

Comment: I also do not do exercises. My usual routine is go to school, go home and do homeworks. Lunch and dinner in between.

Comment: It could be that with only two meals you are not getting enough energy. I think you are still below the age of 20 and then your body will be configured a lot more toward sleeping more so that it can repair itself better and grow. Older people will have an easier time functioning with 6 hours of sleep, but then their bodies are not repairing themsleves as well and they age more rapidly (how does someone of age 30 look 15 years later and compare that to someone who is 15). So, I think you should eat and exercise more and accept that you need (more than) 8 hours of sleep.